# Extern typedef for a Queue

Tags: c

I have a `Queue` which is defined around an `Item` type. For example, if I want a queue of integers I have the following:

```
// queue.h
typedef int Item;
```

However, I'd like the end-user to define what the `Item` is, and so not have it hardcoded in the header file. Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
// queue.h 
extern typedef Item; // pseudocode

// usersfile.c
typdef struct Item_ {
    char name[50];
} Item;

// or --

typedef int Item;
```

How could that be done?

Comment: this "pseudocode" makes no sense. It is even hard to understand what you want to achieve. Beter try to explain it in English

Comment: @0___________ to say that I have a variable called `Item` defined in another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a void pointer (`void *`) type.

```
typedef void* Item;
```

If you look at the [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/), they have something called [`gpointer`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Basic-Types.html#gpointer) which is what is used refer to arbitrary types a user might want to use in a collection.

Also checkout [`GQueue`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Double-ended-Queues.html), which might be a good reference for your implementation.

Comment: smac89 -- but you lose type safety doing that, right? Is it ever suggested for someone to just change it / hardcode it into the header?

Comment: @David542 You loose no type safety on your end as the implementor if you make sure you are abstracting away everything that may touch the data stored inside the queue. The issue of type safety is off-loaded to the user to ensure they are storing the correct data in the queue. I suggest you have a look at the [source](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/master/glib/gqueue.c) for `GQueue`.